# removing 'sticky navigation' on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code which sticks the navigation to the top of the page when scrolled to it.

HTML

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var s = $("#nav");
  var pos = s.position();                    
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
        s.addClass("stick");
    } else {
        s.removeClass("stick"); 
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

I want to disable this for mobile devices (when the accordion opens it takes up all the screen) but not sure how to change my code

Comment: Depends on how you detect mobile devices. If you are relying on viewport width/height, then implement that check before you add or remove classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this css only solution -

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px)

    .stick {
        position: relative !important;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the device is mobile or by the screen width.

1 - Is a mobile device?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s = $("#nav");
  var pos = s.position();     
  var isMobileDev = isMobile();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if(!isMobileDev) {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick"); 
        }
    }
  });

  function isMobile() {
      var response = false; 
      if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
          || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) { 
         response = true;  
      } 
      return response;
  }
});
```

2 - Width check

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s = $("#nav");
  var pos = s.position();               

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 320) {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick"); 
        }
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: I tried using both versions but it doesn't remove the stick function of my navigation. It is a responsive site so i'd like to use that one

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.

```
@media (max-width: 766px){

    .navbar-fixed-top {
        position: relative;
    }

}
```

[**Fiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/1pcew4pp/)

Comment: it only sticks when scrolled to it, meaning that when it hits the top it gets fixed, it's relative all the other times. Your answer fixes it to the top of the screen all the time